# Forms of multivariate CLT

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-theory

I am looking for a good reference for differnt kinds of multivariate central limit theorems. I was wondering how far the i.i.d. condition of the standard multivariate clt can be relaxed, as in can the random variables be dependent for instance?

Comment: You may take a look at *Stochastic Limit Theory: An Introduction for Econometricicans* by James Davidson. He discusses lots of ways to weaken independence assumptions in the CLT and also how to turn these one-dimensional results into multivariate ones.

Comment: @Davide I think he refers to the problem of showing that an appropriatly rescaled sequence of $n$-dimensional random vectors has asymptotically a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Indeed Michael, you have interpreted my question correctly, thx.

Comment: In the future, this question might be better received at the Stats version of MathOverflow.

Comment: @DavidWhite Which site would that be?

Comment: The site is http://stats.stackoverflow.com.  It's probably true that this question would be better received there, but the reason is *not* that it's statistics and not mathematics.  It's that they're more welcoming of reference-request questions.

Comment: @MarkMeckes Is stats.stackoverflow a project ? I had never heard about it. Is there an announcement somewhere ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: stats.stackoverflow.com (also known as Cross Validated) is yet another site on the StackExchange network, focusing on statistics.  I suppose its existence is advertised wherever StackExchange sites are listed, but I don't personally know where that is.

Comment: @MarkMeckes Ah ok, I well know ! But this is stats.stackexchange, not overflow.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: Sorry!  That was a typo both times.

Answer (score 2):

The classics:

Hall and Heyde's book
[http://www.amazon.com/Martingale-Application-Probability-Mathematical-Statistics/dp/0123193508](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123193508)

Bhattacharya-Rao's book
http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Normal_Approximation_and_Asymptotic_Expa.html?id=H1lOIVHcRDEC&redir_esc=y